# How to scale a object with distance from the center of the canvas in UNITY?

Tags: scrollview, unity-game-engine, scaling

i need to achieve a treadmill effect for the scroll view, i.e while scrolling the center object need to reduce in scale when moving away from center and vice versa? can someone point me in the right direction, im already calculating the center of the scrollview from the elements to achieve the snapping effect.

***Solved** by very cheap method might not be suitable for everyone the process is by getting the distance from the button/elements in the scrollview to the center and learping with the said distance with the amount of scale needed

```
istReposition = center.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position.x - bttn.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position.x;
distance = Mathf.Abs(distReposition);
Vector3 minscale = Vector3.one * maximundistanceScale;
Vector3 maxScale = Vector3.one * minimundistanceScale;
bttn[i].GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = Vector3.Lerp(maxScale,minscale, distance);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Overflow isn't a scripting service: next time please try to post what you've already tried.

Anyway you can do it like this:

- Getting the distance from your UI element to the center of the ScrollView (on the **x** axis only if your treadmill is horizontal or on the **y** axis if it's vertical)
- Dividing this value by half the width of the canvas
- Getting the absolute value of the result
- You now have a value ranging from 0 to 1 (1 being when the element is on the middle of the canvas and 0 on the sides)

A quick implementation of this would be:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(RectTransform))]
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float m_CenterScale;
    [SerializeField]
    private float m_BorderScale;
    [SerializeField]
    private AnimationCurve m_ScalingCurve; // Must be from 1 to 0 on y axis and from 0 to 1 on x axis

    protected override void Update()
    {
        float scrollviewCenterPosition = GetComponentInParent<ScrollRect>().GetComponent<RectTransform>().position.x;
        float distanceFromCenter = transform.position.x - scrollviewCenterPosition ;
        float ratio = Mathf.Abs(distanceFromCenter / (GetComponentInParent<ScrollRect>().GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width * 0.5f));
        float scaleValue = m_BorderScale + (m_CenterScale - m_BorderScale) * m_ScalingCurve.Evaluate(ratio);
        (transform as RectTransform).localScale = Vector3.one * scaleValue;
    }
}
```

Please note I added an `AnimationCurve` property to be able to control the scaling effect easily: the curve should start at [0:1] and end at [1:0] like this:

[image: Animation curve to control the scaling effect.]

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: thanks you.. actually i got it working already thanks for the reply and sorry for not attaching my script it was so spaghetti coded, even i couldn't figure out the heads and tails .. ill mark your answer as a correct one (I didn't try it though) but it will be helpful for others i guess

Comment: You're welcome! If you have time consider posting your working code as an edit to your question or an answer so it can also help future users. Good luck with the rest of your project :)

Comment: done, i pasted only the crucial part i hope its fine